# 'word not in the vocabulary' when evaluating similarity using Gensim Word2Vec.most_similar method

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, similarity

Through the [method](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/gensim.models.Word2Vec.most_similar.html)

`gensim.models.Word2Vec.most_similar`

I get the top-N most similar words.

I trained a model with a list of sentences like

```
list_of_list = [["i like going to the beach"],
                ["the war is over"], 
                ["we are all made of stars"],  
                         ...
                ["i don't know what to do"]] 
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(list_of_list, size=100, window=longest_list, min_count=2)

suggestions = model.most_similar("I don't know what to do", topn=10)
```

and I wanted to evaluate phrases similarity.

If for example I run

```
suggestions = model.most_similar("I don't know what to do", topn=10)
```

It works correctly.

But if I give a subquery like `"to the beach"` or `"what to do"`, it returns an error message because the sub-phrase is not in the vocabulary.

```
 "word 'to the beach' not in vocabulary"
```

How can I solve this issue without training again the model?
How can the model identify the most similar phrases based on a new phrase, not necessary a subphrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are not training the `Word2Vec` model correctly. Sentences should be lists of words not list of single strings. So, if you change it to:

```
list_of_list = [["i like going to the beach"],
                ["the war is over"], 
                ["we are all made of stars"],  
                         ...
                ["i don't know what to do"]]

list_for_training = [sent[0].split() for sent in list_of_list]
```

and use `list_for_training` as the first parameter of the constructor of `Word2Vec`.

Similarly, when calling `most_similar` method, provide a list of strings instead of a string:

```
suggestions = model.most_similar("I don't know what to do".split(), topn=10)
```

or

```
suggestions = model.most_similar("to the beach".split(), topn=10)
```

Comment: yes I don't know why I made this huge mistake. My idea was to find similarity in a unsupervised way between ecommerce titles.

Comment: Because I explained wrongly my problem, is more related to doc2vec [like here](https://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/)